# Android Studio: Can't run emulator in a tool window

Tags: android, emulation

Whenever I try to run the emulator in a tool window, it briefly says **"Connecting to the Emulator"**, and then says that no emulators are running.

I tried creating a new AVD, I even did a clean install of Android Studio.

Running the emulator in standalone mode (a separate window) is fine.

Tested in Arctic Fox and in AS 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation was fixed with the newest emulator update.